# Apache POI: How to update excel file with many formulas?

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

What am I doing wrong?
Value of the cell D5 in file excelFileNew.xlsm is: #DIV/0!
Why?

-- Program output:

```
Formula is: C34
1. case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC --> Last evaluated as: 407.2521754511886
Formula is: C34
```

-- Cell values:

```
Value of the cell D5 in file excelFileOrig.xlsm is: 407,25
Value of the cell D5 in file excelFileNew.xlsm is: #DIV/0!
Value of the cell C8 in file excelFileOrig.xlsm is: 5,0
Value of the cell D5 in file excelFileNew.xlsm is: 15,0
```

-- Code: See in 1 Answer

Comment: What is in `C34`?

Comment: The beginning of the chain looks like this:
D5 =C34
C34 =SUM(A8:A13)
A8 =IFERROR(SUM(B22);0)
A9    "is empty"
A10 =SUM(B24)
A11  "is empty"
A12 =SUM(B26)
A13  "is empty"

B22 =SUM(D12:F12)
B24 =SUM(D14:F14)
B26 =SUM(D16:F16)


D12 =SUM(D30:D40)
E12 =IF(H9="Yes";MAX(E18-(J18-J20)*SheetA!B2;SheetA!C2);MAX(E18-(J18-J20)*SheetA!F3;SheetA!F3)-IF(E9>0;F59;0))
F12 =F228/(D458+E58)*(D82+E82)

D14 =IF(H54>0;D40/H40/I40/J40*H64*I64*J64;0)
E14 =E40/H40*H64+E40/J40*(J64-J40)*0,3
F14 =F40/(D40+E40)*(D64+E64)

etc

Comment: Formulas in a Excel-file
:
AND, FALSE, IF, IFERROR, MAX, OR, SUM, SUMPRODUCT, VLOOKUP

Comment: Formulas in Program with System.out.println(FunctionEval.getSupportedFunctionNames()); 
[ABS, ACOS, ACOSH, ADDRESS, AND, …

IFERROR is missing in Java... Why?!

Comment: So somewhere in this complex chain is a division by zero after setting C8 = 15. But not clear where exactly with the formulas you have shown in your comment. But "IFERROR is missing in apache poi": Please don't use ancient apache poi versions.

Comment: Apache POI version is 3.16

Comment: With workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true); is new file correctly saved. All cells have new values!

Next problem: bad output for new file.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Formula is: C34
cell.getCachedFormulaResultType(): 0
0. case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC --> Last evaluated as: 407.2521754511886
Formula is: C34
cell.getCachedFormulaResultType(): 5
5. case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR -->
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Why CELL_TYPE_ERROR ? All cells have new values in new file...
What needs to be changed in code?

Comment: New code --> See new Answer

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.*;

public class POITestRB {

    static String excelFileOrig = "C:/Test/1.xlsm";
    static String excelFileNew = "C:/Test/excelFileNew.xlsm";
    static FileInputStream fis;
    static XSSFWorkbook workbook;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        fis = new FileInputStream(excelFileOrig);
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        gettingCellContents(workbook, "D5");
        updateCell(workbook, 10.0);
        fis.close();
        workbook.close();

        fis = new FileInputStream(excelFileNew);
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        gettingCellContents(workbook, "D5");
        fis.close();
        workbook.close();

    }


    private static void gettingCellContents(XSSFWorkbook workbook, String cellId) {

        workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);

        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(1);
        CellReference ref = new CellReference(cellId);
        int row = ref.getRow();
        int col = ref.getCol();
        Cell cell = sheet.getRow(row).getCell(col);

        switch (cell.getCellTypeEnum()) {
            case STRING:
                System.out.println(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
                break;
            case NUMERIC:
                if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                    System.out.println(cell.getDateCellValue());
                } else {
                    System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                }
                break;
            case BOOLEAN:
                System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                break;
            case FORMULA:
                System.out.println("Formula is: " + cell.getCellFormula());
                System.out.println("cell.getCachedFormulaResultType(): " + cell.getCachedFormulaResultType());

                switch(cell.getCachedFormulaResultType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        System.out.println("0. case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC --> Last evaluated as: " + cell.getNumericCellValue());
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        System.out.println("4. case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING --> Last evaluated as \"" + cell.getRichStringCellValue() + "\"");
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                        System.out.println("5. case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR --> ");
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case BLANK:
                System.out.println();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("default");
        }
    }

    public static void updateCell(XSSFWorkbook workbook, Double newData) {
        try {
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(1);
            CellReference ref = new CellReference("C8");
            int row = ref.getRow();
            int col = ref.getCol();
            Cell cell = sheet.getRow(row).getCell(col);
            if (cell != null) {
                cell.setCellValue(newData);
            }

            workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().clearAllCachedResultValues();
            workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();

            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(excelFileNew);
            workbook.write(os);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

// output:
// Formula is: C34
// cell.getCachedFormulaResultType(): 0
// 0. case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC --> Last evaluated as: 407.2521754511886
// Formula is: C34
// cell.getCachedFormulaResultType(): 5
// 5. case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR -->
```